# Concatenating data from Kendo Datasources in to a new array

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource, jslinq

I'm trying to concat the selected items from 2 grids in to an array for further processing but I don't want to affect any change in either data source and this is proving problematic as the first data source seems to (after the concat) contain the items I pull from the first ...

```
var allItems = JSLINQ(grid1.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data())
     .Concat(grid2.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data())
     .ToArray();
```

the source code for the concat function in JSLINQ is doing this ...

```
Concat: function (array) {
    var arr = array.items || array;
    return new JSLINQ(this.items.concat(arr));
}
```

this.items is from what I can tell the value of "grid1.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()"
and i'm trying to build a new array with the items in "grid2.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()" which I then intend to filter based on selection criteria.

does anyone have any experience with this / a means to say "I want a copy of the data item from the source that's not connected to the source"?

UPDATE:
The base functionality here relies on having a standard JS array, it seems that kendo returns an observable array object (specific to kendo, and missing the concat function).

The implementation above results in an exception on the concat call (because it doesn't exist), so I rewrote the function to something like this ...

```
Concat: function (array) {
    //var arr = array.items || array;
    //return new JSLINQ(this.items.concat(arr));

    var retVal = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.items[i]));
        retVal.push(clone);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array[i]));
        this.items.push(clone);
    }

    return new JSLINQ(retVal);
},
```

That results in the duplicate problem I mentioned above.

So it seems that the error I have here is something to do with observable array, but I don't know how to get a "detatched item" / "array" from the data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turns out the toJSON() method on an observable array turns the observable array in to an array (odd naming, but hey this is kendo right!)

In short, by manipulating my call input to the JSLINQ method to include this I then have normal JS behaviour as I would expect ...

```
var allItems = JSLINQ(grid1.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().toJSON())
     .Concat(grid2.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().toJSON())
     .ToArray();
```

Comment: toJSON() works on more complex observable objects as well, stripping off all the methods and events to return a new non-observable object. Another example usage is for cloning an observable by calling toJSON() and feeding the result into the constructor of a new one.